# How to determine key frames in a video for video classification?

Tags: classification, computer-vision, image-preprocessing

How to detect changes between when the changes between 2 frames of videos that are significant enough to be counted for video classification? Thinking of the problem as analogous to edge detection in an image where the change between 2 adjacent pixel is threshold-ed to detect an edge.

Answer (score 1):

Most video formats should already mark such frames marked as "Key Frames" (Frames 1 in this example).

[image]

It is possible to get identifiers of such frames (or split video around such frame). For example, mkvmerge tool.

https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html

http://nickyguides.digital-digest.com/keyframes.htm